# Sobrecarga de funciones en C estándar

Tags: c, funciones, sobrecarga, estándares

**¿Existe alguna manera de sobrecargar funciones en C estándar?**

Es decir, si se pueden definir varias funciones con el mismo nombre pero con un número o tipo de argumentos distintos entre ellas. Por ejemplo:

```
int f_sobrecargada(void);
int f_sobrecargada(int);
int f_sobrecargada(char *);
int f_sobrecargada(int, char *);
```

¿Existe alguna manera de conseguir esto sin tener que dar un nombre distinto a cada función en C estándar?

Answer (score 6):

No hay manera de poder sobrecargar funciones en C estándar directamente, es decir, no existe tal característica que forme parte del estándar. Pero, sí hay una manera de poder conseguir (parcialmente) sobrecargar funciones en C.

A partir del estándar *C11* se añadió una característica llamada **expresiones de tipo genérico** o **expresión de selección genérica** a través de la palabra reservada **`_Generic`**. Vamos a ver cómo funciona con un ejemplo:

```
_Generic(expr, float: 2.0,
               char *: "2",
               int: 2,
               default: NULL);
```

`_Generic` es un operador en tiempo de compilación que, de manera parecida al operador `switch`, comprueba durante la compilación el tipo de dato de una expresión y, en función del tipo obtenido, devuelve un resultado asociado a la lista de tipos añadida al resto del operador `_Generic`.

En el ejemplo anterior, dependiendo del tipo de dato de `expr` devolvería en tiempo de compilación el valor asociado a dicho tipo.

Este operador `_Generic` puede ser utilizado para implementar un comportamiento similar a la sobrecarga de funciones. Vamos a ver cómo se haría con el siguiente ejemplo:

```
int f_sobrecargada_int(int);
int f_sobrecargada_pchar(char *);

#define f_sobrecargada(_1) _Generic((_1),                      \
                                    int: f_sobrecargada_int,   \
                                    char *: f_sobrecargada_pchar)(_1)
```

En primer lugar declaramos los prototipos de las funciones (que estarán definidas en otro archivo) con los distintos tipos de argumentos. Cada función tiene su propio nombre para no crear colisiones.

A continuación, se define una macro con el nombre genérico de la función que aceptará todos los tipos posibles de argumentos. Esta macro es un operador `_Generic` que simplemente devuelve en tiempo de compilación el nombre de la función correcta dependiendo del tipo de dato del argumento. De esta manera, en nuestro código podríamos usar el nombre `f_sobrecargado()` sin preocuparnos el tipo de dato del argumento que le estemos pasando.

Para el caso de tener distintas funciones con **distinto número de argumentos (*pero con el tipo del primer argumento distinto en todas ellas*)**, se puede implementar como el siguiente código de ejemplo:

```
int f_sobrecargada_pchar(char *);
int f_sobrecargada_int_pchar(int, char *);

#define PRIMER(_1, ...)  (_1)

#define f_sobrecargada(...)                \
  _Generic(PRIMER(__VA_ARGS__),            \
           int: f_sobrecargada_int_pchar,  \
           char *: f_sobrecargada_pchar)(__VA_ARGS__)
```

En este caso se usaría la característica del número variable de argumentos en la macro con `__VA_ARGS__`. Como en dicha macro no sabemos cuántos argumentos se necesitarán para ejecutar la función (ya que puede obtenerse cualquiera de las dos funciones), se pasa por argumento directamente `__VA_ARGS__` con los valores que se pasaron a la macro, sean cuales fuesen. También es necesario implementar otra macro `PRIMER_ARG` para obtener el primer argumento del cual se comprobará su tipo en `_Generic`.

Se puede también dar el caso de tener que **anidar operadores `_Generic`**, como el siguiente ejemplo:

```
int f_sobrecargada_pchar_pchar(char *, char *);
int f_sobrecargada_pchar_int(char *, int);
int f_sobrecargada_int_int(int, int);

#define PRIMER(_1, ...)  (_1)
#define RESTO(_1, ...) __VA_ARGS__

#define f_sobrecargada(...)                   \
  _Generic(                                   \
    PRIMER(__VA_ARGS__),                      \
    int: f_sobrecargada_int_int,              \
    char *:                                   \
      _Generic(PRIMER(RESTO(__VA_ARGS__)),    \
               int: f_sobrecargada_pchar_int, \
               char *: f_sobrecargada_pchar_pchar))(__VA_ARGS__)
```

En este caso todas las funciones tienen el mísmo número de argumentos para evitar problemas (explicados más adelante). Si no fuese así, puede darse el caso de que la expresión dentro del `_Generic` anidado esté vacía al intentar acceder a un segundo argumento inexistente.

### Problemas

¿Y qué pasa con las funciones sin argumentos (void)? Este caso es más complicado, ya que `_Generic` necesita una expresión a comprobar su tipo y, si a la macro no se le pasa ningún argumento, `_Generic` no tendrá expresión a comprobar.

Una posible solución es sumar el valor `+0` a la expresión a comprobar en `_Generic`. Veamos cómo queda el código:

```
int f_sobrecargada_void(void);
int f_sobrecargada_double(double);
int f_sobrecargada_pchar(char *);

#define f_sobrecargada(_1) _Generic((_1+0),                         \
                                    double: f_sobrecargada_double,  \
                                    int: f_sobrecargada_void,       \
                                    char *: f_sobrecargada_pchar)(_1)
```

Al añadir `+0` en la expresión `_1`, la expresión resultante siempre tiene un tipo de dato a comprobar, el cual dependería del tipo de dato de `_1`:

- Si el tipo de dato de `_1` es `char`, `short` y `int`, la expresión se promociona a `int`.
- Si `_1` está vacío, la expresión se promociona a `int`.
- Para el resto de tipos de `_1` la expresión se promociona al tipo de `_1` (incluso con punteros).

Si entre los tipos posibles de los primeros argumentos que admiten las distintas funciones no está `char`, `short` o `int` (como en el ejemplo anterior), no existe ningún problema. Sólo se promocionaría a `int` en el caso de no haber introducido ningún argumento, sin generar ningún conflicto entre tipos.

Si entre los posibles tipos de los primeros argumentos de las funciones está `char`, `short` o `int`, entonces existe un conflicto porque al introducir alguno de estos tres tipos de datos o ninguno (vacío), en todos estos casos promociona a `int`. Entonces, ¿cómo se sabe qué función elegir en esta situación?

Para explicar una **posible solución**, vamos a fijarnos en el siguiente código:

```
int f_sobrecargada_int(int);
int f_sobrecargada_void(void);

static const int _0 = 0;

#define f_sobrecargada(...)                   \
  _Generic((_1&_0),                           \
           int: f_sobrecargada_int,           \
           default: f_sobrecargada_void))(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Esta solución comprueba el resultado de la expresión `_1&_0`. Si `_1` tiene un tipo `int` el resultado de la expresión será de tipo `int`. Si en cambio `_1` no tiene nada, el resultado de la expresión será un puntero.
Esta solución tiene algunos problemas, como por ejemplo que no puede usarse cuando existen otros tipos como punteros o punto flotante, ya que aplicar el operador `&` con un segundo operando entero no está permitido para estos tipos.

Otra posible **solución usando casting** sería como se detalla en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
int f_sobrecargada_int(int);
int f_sobrecargada_void(void);

#define f_sobrecargada(...)                       \
  _Generic(((int)_1+0.0),                         \
           int: f_sobrecargada_void,              \
           double: f_sobrecargada_int))(__VA_ARGS__)
```

En este ejemplo, el contenido de la expresión se promoción a `int` en caso de que `_1` esté vacío. Si `_1` contiene un tipo `int` la expresión se promociona a `double`.

Esta solución sólo sirve para distinguir entre argumento vacío (promocionado a `int`) y argumento no vacío (promocionado a `double`). No se puede usar para diferenciar entre distintos tipos de datos.

El problema de esta solución es que no puede haber implicados tipos puntero ya que `_1` no se envuelve entre paréntesis para evitar el error de expresión vacía en caso de que `_1` esté vacío. Es decir, si una de las funciones sobrecargadas admitiese por ejemplo `char *`, y ejecutase la macro pasando por argumento algo así: `"cad1" "cad2"`, la macro sólo haría el casting para `"cad1"` generando un error. Además, incluso en el caso de que se pasase por argumento un puntero limpio, el casting genera un aviso de conversión de datos.

**Nota:** Cuando en una misma posición de argumentos de las distintas funciones hay un tipo `void` (vacío), `int` y `puntero`, no se puede usar ninguna de las dos soluciones anteriores para distinguir entre ellos porque el puntero generaría conflictos.

### Resumen

El operador `_Generic` puede ser una solución para simular sobrecarga de funciones en C, pero sólo bajo ciertas condiciones que no generen conflictos con las macros generadas.

Comment: no se del tema pero se ve el esfuerzo realizado. Gracias por aportar. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b Gracias. Llevo dos días con ello y aun así no he encontrado una solución completa. Explico todo lo que he encontrado o descubierto por mi cuenta en la entrada.

Comment: De todas formas, si te surge un tema así puede ser buena idea publicar la pregunta y darte un par de días para elaborar la respuesta. Así animas a que la comunidad participe y puede que alguno te sorprenda con su respuesta

Comment: @eferion Muy bien. Lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima vez.

Comment: Te lo comento porque si alguien entra y ve que te has autorespondido lo mismo toma como una pérdida de tiempo leer la pregunta y pensar alternativas

Comment: [Que nunca se olvide que el abuso de las macro puede ser peligroso](http://www.ioccc.org/2004/vik2.c).