# Representación en memoria de cadenas unicode y codificación utf-8 en Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, python-2.x, unicode

En relación al formato unicode y utf-8 en Python 3 me gustaría hacer las siguientes preguntas:

- ¿El formato unicode de Python 3 guarda todos los posibles caracteres existentes o solo una parte? He visto que en unicode existen distintos planos donde se agrupan los caracteres y no sé si Python abarca todos.
- ¿Cuánto tamaño ocupa cada carácter unicode de una cadena en memoria? Al haber caracteres cuyo valor entra en 8, 16 o 32 bits, no sé cuánto tamaño ocupa cada carácter en memoria.
- ¿Los caracteres de una cadena unicode están en memoria en formato utf-8?

Comment: Si bien es honrosa tu disposición a explicar, creo que ahora mismo la pregunta es un pelín genérica, empezando por el título. ¿Qué problema concreto quieres abordar? Si se trata de tres preguntas, ¿no sería mejor publicar otras tantas publicaciones?

Comment: @fedorqui No, porque la respuesta de cada una de ellas necesita de las otras. Van enlazadas.

Comment: No, esperaaaa. Creo que el título ahora describe mejor el problema. El tema es presentar preguntas cuyo enunciado pueda derivar en contenido interesante, útil... y concreto. Creo que puliendo un poco lo que has publicado lo conseguiremos. Es solamente cuestión de ajustar un poco al formato indicado en [ask]. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una cosa es el contenido del texto del archivo o módulo a ser ejecutado por el intérprete de Python, y otra es el formato en memoria de las cadena (*strings*) usadas al ejecutar del código.

### Contenido del archivo

Cuando se escribe un módulo, archivo o *script* en Python, en el editor de texto se especifica qué tipo de codificación desea ser usada al guardar el archivo. De este modo, en el disco duro se guarda ese archivo con un tipo de codificación en concreto (*ascii*, *utf-8*, *utf-16*, etc). El intérprete de Python, al ejecutar dicho módulo tiene que leer el archivo y por lo tanto tiene que conocer qué tipo de codificación fue usada para guardarlo, porque en caso contrario no podría decodificar correctamente el contenido del archivo.

Python 2 por defecto decodifica los archivos como *ascii*, y Python 3 los decodifica por defecto como *utf-8*. La manera de asegurar siempre que el intérprete de Python lea correctamente el contenido del módulo es informando explícitamente mediante la directiva `coding` qué tipo de codificación fue usada por el editor de texto para guardar ese archivo. De esta manera, aunque la configuración por defecto del intérprete de Python 2 o 3 cambie, nunca dará problemas.

Resumiendo, indicar siempre en la primera o segunda línea del archivo fuente la directiva `#coding=X`, donde X es la codificación que fue usada por el editor de texto para guardar el archivo.

### Formato de cadenas

Por otro lado, están las cadenas de caracteres `str` usadas en memoria durante la ejecución de un programa en Python. Estas cadenas se pueden guardar en memoria como dos tipos principales: *byte* o *unicode*.

- **Las cadenas tipo *byte***: son simplemente secuencias de valores de 8 bits, por lo tanto no se puede guardar en este formato ningún carácter cuyo punto de código esté fuera de los primeros 256 valores (tabla ASCII extendida). También se puede guardar un carácter indicando explícitamente su valor de punto de código mediante la secuencia de escape `'\xNN'`, donde `NN` representan un valor en hexadecimal dentro del rango 0-255.

  Este tipo de cadenas son las utilizadas por defecto en Python 2, mientras que en Python 3 para poder ser utilizadas se tiene que indicar expícitamente el prefijo `b` antes del literal que representa la cadena.
- **Las cadenas tipo *unicode***: permiten la representación de cualquier carácter existente. Para ello, existen una serie de tablas de valores *unicode*, divididas por planos, con la asociación de cada carácter a su respectivo punto de código o valor. El plano *unicode* más utilizado es el primer plano (plano básico multilingüe), el cual necesita hasta 16 bits por carácter y puede representar hasta 65535 caracteres (incluido el español). Para poder usar el resto de planos se necesitarían como máximo 24 bits por carácter pero, como en memoria se usan espacios de 8, 16 o 32 bits, es inevitable utilizar 32 bits para caracteres cuyo punto de código es mayor de 16 bits, desperdiciando 8 bits.

  La manera de representar valores de punto de código *unicode* en una cadena de caracteres es mediante `'\uNNNN'` (N es hexadecimal) para puntos de código entre 8 y 16 bits, y `'\U0010NNNN'` para puntos de código entre 16 y 24 bits (ocupando este último en memoria 32 bits).

  En Python 3 las cadenas se guardan por defecto en formato *unicode*, mientras que en Python 2 es necesario indicar el prefijo `u` antes del literal representando la cadena.

  En el momento de compilar una implementación del intérprete Python, ésta se puede configurar para fijar el máximo rango de caracteres *unicode* que puede manejar. Para ello existe un parámetro de configuración `--enable-unicode` cuyos valores pueden ser `latin-1`, `ucs2` y `ucs4`.

  - `latin-1`: las cadenas *unicode* sólo podrán guardar en memoria 8 bits por carácter, es decir, la tabla *ASCII* extendida.
  - `ucs2`: las cadenas *unicode* sólo podrán guardar en memoria 16 bits por carácter, es decir, el primer plano *unicode* o plano básico multilingüe.
  - `ucs4`: las cadenas *unicode* podrán guardar en memoria hasta 32 bits por carácter, es decir, todo el espectro posible de caracteres (aunque los caracteres que necesiten más de 16 bits desperdiciarán 8 bits ya que no existen puntos de código *unicode* mayores de 24 bits).

  ¿Qué ocurre si guardamos en memoria una cadena *unicode* mezclando caracteres que se pueden representar en 8 bits, 16 bits o 32 bits? Pues que Python fija el tamaño de cada carácter al máximo tamaño de entre todos los caracteres de la cadena. Por lo tanto, si un solo carácter necesita 32 bits para poder guardar su punto de código, el resto de caracteres usarán 32 bits aunque no necesiten más de 8. Esto se debe a que **Python no usa ningún tipo de codificación (*utf-8*, *utf-16*, etc) para representar las cadenas *unicode* en memoria, sino simplemente guarda el valor del punto de código asociado a cada carácter**. De este modo, como no puede saber qué tamaño se usó para guardar cada carácter, simplifica fijando todos a un solo tamaño.

---

Es importante recalcar que la manera como se guardan las cadenas *unicode* en memoria no tienen nada que ver con los tipos de codificación (*utf-8*, *utf-16*, etc). Los tipos de codificación (*utf* para el formato *unicode*) son una forma de serializar el contenido del archivo para manejarlo mucho mejor posteriormente: guardar en disco duro, enviar por la red, etc. Las cadenas con formato *unicode* durante la ejecución del programa se guardan en memoria como secuencias de puntos de código y nunca se guardan codificadas como, por ejemplo, *utf-8* (a no ser que voluntariamente se guarde una cadena no como *unicode*, sino como una secuencia de *bytes* cuyo contenido esté en algún tipo de codificación).

Las cadenas *unicode* que forman parte de un archivo fuente son codificadas junto con el resto del contenido del archivo cuando éste se guarda en el disco duro, y son decodificadas posteriormente cuando dicho archivo es leído. Es decir, usar un tipo de codificación para codificar un archivo es una forma de representar de forma óptima el contenido del archivo como una secuencia de bytes, indicando los límites de cada carácter mediante cabeceras de bits. De esta forma no es necesario (como el caso de cadenas unicode en memoria) un tamaño fijo para todos los caracteres, sino que es variable, siendo conocido a la hora de decodificar el contenido.

Comment: Hola, vengo viendo que tú mismo abres una pregunta y la contestas en pocos minutos. Incluso cuando [te han recomendado que dejes pasar un intervalo de tiempo para que otros puedan aportar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/84185/sobrecarga-de-funciones-en-c-est%c3%a1ndar/84186#comment155690_84186). He abierto una discusión en meta para saber si este uso sería el apropiado del sitio. Por favor, si quieres comentar sobre ello ve a https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2386/preguntas-y-respuestas-del-mismo-usuario-de-forma-repetida Saludos.

Comment: En mi opinión, atenta un poco contra el espíritu del sitio. Es por ello que abro el debate enlazado más arriba.

Comment: Carlos, considera marcar tu respuesta como wiki de comunidad.

Comment: @Jorgesys Vale, lo hago ahora mismo.